# How to create a column for below given rowData in agGrid table in Angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to create a **column** for below given **rowData** in agGrid table in Angular which will render the **address** column on its own? [Image URL - Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRT1w.png)

```
  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
  ];

  rowData = [
      {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000, address: [{name: 'Showroom 1', city: 'Miami', ZIP: 67202}, {name: 'Showroom 2', city: 'Mesa', ZIP: 67204}]},
      {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000, address: [{name: 'Showroom 1', city: 'Fresno', ZIP: 67203}, {name: 'Showroom 2', city: 'Oakland', ZIP: 67205}]},
      {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000, address: [{name: 'Showroom 1', city: 'Kansas City', ZIP: 67201}, {name: 'Showroom 2', city: 'Long Beach', ZIP: 67206}]}
```

Comment: You have an array for addresses. Please specify your requirement. How do you want to represent it on UI? Do you want different columns for different addresses or you want to display in a single column?

Comment: @DurgeshPal - I want my table to be displayed in a format which I have added in the following URL. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRT1w.png

Comment: So have you found the solution or need help?

Comment: Not exactly yet. I use setterValue method with index hard-coded as I have less number of columns.

Comment: I have shared the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help. Update it accordingly.

```
  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'},
    {
      headerName: 'Address', field: 'address',
      cellRenderer: (params) => {
         let cellContent = '<ol>';
         for (var i = 0; i < params.value.length; i++) {
             cellContent += `<li>${params.value[i].name}, ${params.value[i].city}</li>`;
         }
         cellContent += '</ol>';
     }
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing address in Showroom 1 and Showroom 2, you have to use the column group.
The below code will help you to show city and zip in your showrooms.
Add these column object in your columnDefs.

```
{
        headerName: "Showroom 1",
        children: [
          {
            headerName: "City",
            field: "address",
            valueFormatter: param => param.data.address[0].city
          },
          {
            headerName: "Zip",
            field: "address",
            valueFormatter: param => param.data.address[0].ZIP
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        headerName: "Showroom 2",
        children: [
          {
            headerName: "City",
            field: "address",
            valueFormatter: param => param.data.address[1].city
          },
          {
            headerName: "Zip",
            field: "address",
            valueFormatter: param => param.data.address[1].ZIP
          }
        ]
      }
```